# difference between "addressable" and "address" in memory?

Tags: memory-management

I'm struggle on this practice question from this [site](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/paging-formulas-practice-problems/)....

> Calculate the number of bits required in the address for memory having
> size of 16 GB. Assume the memory is 4-byte addressable.

MY QUESTION IS: what is the difference between an "address" and "the memory is 4 byte addressable"?

I understand an address would be its location in memory that is represented by bits, such as 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the address. But I'm confused about addressable in this question and how that's different than address

2^n * 4 bytes = 2^34
The solution is 32 bits

Comment: On further research I think that the address is the unique location of the memory, and the addressable is how much data can be stored at that address.... that's what I got from this site: https://leescomputingblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/addressability-and-memory/#:~:text=Addressability%20Addressability%20is%20the%20way%20in%20which%20the,access%204%20memory%20locations%20and%20a%203%20bit%E2%80%A6

Comment: *Address* is a label that identifies a memory location. *The memory is $4$ byte addressable* means that you have labels that refer to memory locations of size $4$ bytes. You don't have names for smaller sizes. For example, if we have a memory of $12$ bytes and the memory is $4$ byte addressable, then we can have $3$ blocks of memory to which we can assign an address. Their addresses could be `Memory block 1`, `The glorious block 2` and `Ceres`. Instead of fancy long name what is common is for the addresses to be binary numbers. Since there are $3$ addresses, then we need at least $2$ bits.

Comment: In your problem, instead of $12$ bytes, you have $16$ GB ${}=2^{10}$ bytes. The memory is $4$ byte addressable. So, we can have $2^{10}/4=2^8$ different addresses. So, we need $8$ bits to encode all addresses.

Comment: @plop Make an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Address* is a label that identifies a memory location. *The memory is $4$ byte addressable* means that you have labels that refer to memory locations of size $4$ bytes. You don't have names for smaller sizes. For example, if we have a memory of $12$ bytes and the memory is $4$ byte addressable, then we can have $3$ blocks of memory to which we can assign an address. Their addresses could be `Memory block 1`, `The glorious block 2` and `Ceres`. Instead of fancy long names what is common is for the addresses to be binary numbers. Since there are $3$ addresses, then we need at least $2$ bits.

In your problem, instead of $12$ bytes, you have $16$ GB ${}=2^{34}$ bytes. The memory is $4$ byte addressable. So, we can have $2^{34}/4=2^{32}$ different addresses. So, we need $32$ bits to encode all addresses.

Comment: 16GB = 2^34 bytes or I'm missing something ?

Comment: 210 bytes seems to be missing a superscript.

Comment: @plop [Rejecting an edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/81319) and then making the same changes yourself instead is not typically considered good manners. I'm glad it's fixed though.